# SQL delete parent records with no child records

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to delete all `CombinableOrders` which have no `Orders` associated with them

My attempt

```
DELETE 
 FROM CombinableOrders pr    
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Orders cr WHERE pr.Id = cr.CombinableOrder_Id)
```

Sql server error

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

I know this must be simple

**Update**

I think the pr and cr were causing the problem and sql was giving me an error for a previous statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE
    CombinableOrders 
FROM 
    CombinableOrders
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE CombinableOrders.Id = Orders.CombinableOrder_Id)
```

Comment: i think the pr and cr was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE 
 FROM CombinableOrders pr    
 WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders cr WHERE pr.Id = cr.CombinableOrder_Id) = 0)
```